# Do a SAS FIND/INDEX for search terms and put search term in a new field (NewN) if found

Tags: select, while-loop, sas

With this code I intend to do a dynamic search  in Name field and enter the search term (a macrovariable sn_term&i) if found into NewN.

I am having issues with the outputting of the results; the last search term tend to overwrite the previous ones.

```
%macro mstrial;
    data  newlbname;
    set  SmplEHM;
    
    %let i=1;
    %Do %until(&i>&p);
    
    
    select;
        when ((find(Name,"&&sn_term&i"))GE 1)
        %let Mvname= &&sn_term&i;
        NewN = strip(symget('Mvname'));
        otherwise ;
        
        end;
    
    
     %Let i=%eval(&i+1);
    %end;
    run; 
    %mend ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, each Name value may include multiple search terms, that's why you use DO-loop to iterate through all terms, right? Then it's kind of expected to have only the last found term because on each 'successful' iteration (when term is found) you are re-writing your NewN variable with current search term. If you want to output them all in one variable, then you could do a concatenation like this:

```
NewN=catx(",",NewN,&Mvname);
```

BTW, is there any specific reason for using DO WHILE loop? It'd be more concise to use DO TO:

```
%do i=1 %to &p;

  ...

%end;
```